# Understanding how to bind parameters and insert data in Adodb

Tags: php, sql, parameters, bind, adodb

I was told to use bind parameters so that I could insert text into my db that had quotes in it.  But, I am pretty confused when it comes to how to do this, the commands seem confusing to me.

So, if I had a php string, that contained html, how would I insert this into my DB using bind parameters?

I wanted to INSERT it, how would I do this?

```
$str = '<div id="test"><a href="#">Test string in db</a></div> string content';
```

I was told to use something like:

```
$rs = $db->Execute('select * from table where val=?', array('10'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **[mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)** should do the trick too, it escapes the quotes automatically after which you can insert data into the database, consider this example:

```
$str = '<div id="test"><a href="#">Test string in db</a></div> string content';
$str_escaped = mysql_real_escape_string($str);
```

Now you can safely use the `$str_escaped` variable to insert data into the database. Furthermore, it is useful in preventing SQL injection attacks.

Comment: What? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353666/php-is-mysql-real-escape-string-sufficient-for-cleaning-user-input

Comment: @jasonbar: could you be more specific?

Comment: I mean, you just argued that `mysql_real_escape_string()` is not sufficient for preventing SQL injections. Now it is? This also doesn't address the question.

Comment: @jasonbar: i said "mysql_real_escape_string is not sufficient in all situations but it is definitely very good friend." you see i did not reject it totally, i said it is good too, it is a very good friend and then i said but prepared statements were **better**. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: @Sarfraz: He's actually using prepared statements here, though. I understand and agree with your position. Also, You have a typo "mysql-real-escape-string"

Comment: @jasonbar: thanks for that type info, whatever, i don't think my answer is wrong, we are not comparing mysql_real and prepared statemen in this question. Thanks again :(

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used ADODB for a while but I believe this should work, no?

```
$str = '<div id="test"><a href="#">Test string in db</a></div> string content';
$rs = $db->Execute('select * from table where val=?', array($str));
```

Answer (score 0):

The ?'s in the SQL serve as placeholders for values that are bound to the statement.

When executed, ADO is executing (given your example)

```
select * from table where val=10
```

You should be able to construct your insert SQL roughly as:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`col1`, `col2` ...) VALUES(?, ? ...)
```

Passing in your values (in the correct order) will render the appropriate query.

Comment: How would I do an UPDATE statement with binding?  I currently have: "UPDATE x_ast_attr SET cust_val = '$attr' WHERE id='$this->assetid'"

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from the CodeIgniter framework:

```
function compile_binds($sql, $binds)
{
    if (strpos($sql, '?') === FALSE)
    {
        return $sql;
    }

    if ( ! is_array($binds))
    {
        $binds = array($binds);
    }

    // Get the sql segments around the bind markers
    $segments = explode('?', $sql);

    // The count of bind should be 1 less then the count of segments
    // If there are more bind arguments trim it down
    if (count($binds) >= count($segments)) {
        $binds = array_slice($binds, 0, count($segments)-1);
    }

    // Construct the binded query
    $result = $segments[0];
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($binds as $bind)
    {
        $result .= mysql_real_escape_string($bind);
        $result .= $segments[++$i];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Then you could have a function:

```
function query($sql, $binds)
{
    return $db->Execute(compile_binds($sql, $binds));
}

$query = query('select * from table where val=?', array('10'));
```