# Why is my code not working when trying to prevent Sql injection?

Tags: php, html, sql

I am a young developer attempting to prevent Sql injections on a site that I didnt originally code myself. I have read many articles about injections and theory behind them but I cannot seem to get this right. Please help me before I put my head through this monitor. 
Thanks
    My Monitor

here is the code:

```
<div id="main">
<div id="header"><? include('site_headergraphics.php'); ?></div>
<table width="800" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" 
class="content">
  <tr>
    <td width="800" valign="top">
      <div style="padding:10px;">


  <? if($_SESSION[$_SESSION['SFIX'].'_owner_id'] == ''){ ?>
  <br><br>
        <form name="balance_login" method="post" action="<? if ($_GET['passthru']){    
?>?passthru=<?= $_GET['passthru'] ?><? } else { ?>?<? } ?>">
      <input name="action" type="hidden" value="login" />
      <table width="780" border="0" cellpadding="5" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr>
          <td><table width="780" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" 
bgcolor="#F7C30F" class="body_text">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" align="left" class="rightmenu"><?= $passmessage ?><?= 
$specialmessage ?></td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top" class="rightmenu">To sign on, 
enter your information below.</td>
                  <td width="412" rowspan="5" valign="top"><p>Welcome to Mediterranean 
Wellness!</p>
                  <p>Ready to join us?  You can <a 
href="index.php?section=payment">GET STARTED here. </a></p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
              <td width="121" align="right" class="rightmenu">Username:</td>
                  <td width="217"><input name="username" type="text" class="body_text" 
id="username" /></td>

                  <!--Added in the prevent SQL code injections-->
                  <?php /*?><?php unset($FindUser);       
                        if(isset($_POST['username']))
                        {
                            $_POST['username'] = 
trim($_POST['username']);
                            if(preg_match('/^[a-
zA-Z0-9^$.*+\[\]{,}]{1,32}$/u', $_POST['username']))
                                $FindUser = 
$_POST['username'];
                        }
                         ?><?php */?>
                </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
              <td align="right" class="rightmenu">Password:</td>
              <td><input name="password" type="password" class="body_text" 
id="password" /></td>
                <?php /*?><?php unset($FindPass);
                        if(isset($_POST['password']))
                        {
                            $_POST['password'] = 
trim($_POST['password']);
                            if(preg_match('/^[a-
zA-Z0-9^$.*+\[\]{,}]{1,32}$/u', $_POST['password']))
                                $$FindPass = 
$_POST['password'];
                        }
                         ?><?php */?>
                         <!--End of code added in the prevent SQL code injections-->
            </tr>

            <tr valign="top">
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td><input name="Submit" type="submit" class="body_text" 
value="Login" />

                   <?php 
                    function make_safe($variable) {
                        $variable = 
mysql_real_escape_string(trim($variable));
                        return $variable;
                    }

                    $username = make_safe($_POST['username']);
                    $password = make_safe($_POST['password']);
                    $check = mysql_query("SELECT Username, 
Password, UserLevel FROM Users WHERE Username = '".$username."' and Password = 
'".$password."'");

                    ?>

                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <a href="?section=forgot">Forgot your username or password?</a></td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    <? } else {  ?>
    <p class="body_text">You must <a href="?user_action=logout">logout</a> to continue 
to this page</p>
    <? } ?>
      </div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your `make_safe` function defined?  Also it would probably help to remove all the HTML from your code sample for clarity, as it has not relevance to the data sanitizing effort.

Comment: How exactly is your code "not working"?

Comment: Sidenote: `$$FindPass = $_POST['password'];` should probably be `$FindPass = $_POST['password'];`. And regarding `make_safe` it's in there, way down to the end.

Comment: The general idea will be to filter the username and password before using in the query. You might be doing this with make_safe(), but we can't see. Even better, do this verification as the user's entering it so you can provide help with the correct format. Also, checkout PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

Comment: `but I cannot seem to get this right` are you serious ?? What am I suppose to do with that statement ? Please tell us more about the problem!! are you getting any error ?

Comment: Side note: this is the proper way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1329367

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to avoid SQL injections is to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) when you query the database.

Also you should clean up your code to make it better readable, and using design patterns like MVC would give it all a better structure.

Comment: See also http://bobby-tables.com/php.html for a crash course in the PHP way to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score -1):

mysql_* is being deprecated and won't work in newer version- you should checkout [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Specifically the [bind_param](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)() function- this is how you should be handling user input now (mysql_real_escape_String() isn't perfect)

That said, you are never connecting to the database in your code- without an active DB connection mysql_real_escape_string() will not work

Comment: `mysql_* is being depricated and won't work in newer version` which version did it not work ?

Comment: @Deepak in the newer versions it will not but for now it is still working

Comment: @rsz Yes i agree with u!! From his answer it looks like it is not working in newer versions... Should have be said as future versions!!

Comment: What exactly does "`mysql_real_escape_String()` isn't perfect" mean? Which cases are not covered?

Comment: UTF8 characters OR if you forget quotes - mysql_query("select * from user where id=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[id])); could still be injected (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353666/php-is-mysql-real-escape-string-sufficient-for-cleaning-user-input)    PDO/MySQLI puts the quotes around strings for you - you can't forget them.

Comment: for UTF8 - mysql_real_escape_String() doesn't know what character set your Mysql Connection is using (if you aren't using latin) - so it won't escape all the characters it should - http://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html