# Should I use mysqli_real_escape_string or should I use prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, mysql-real-escape-string

Should I use `mysqli_real_escape_string` or should I use prepared statements?

I've seen a tutorial now explaining prepared statements but I've seen them do the same thing as `mysqli_real_escape_string` but it uses more lines

Are there any benefits for prepared statements?
What do you think is the best method to use?

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353666/php-is-mysql-real-escape-string-sufficient-for-cleaning-user-input

Comment: I think this will fix your doubts,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496

Thanks

Comment: If you're looking for performance you should use real_escape_string instead of prepared statement because is twice faster. Details here: https://www.jimwestergren.com/pdo-versus-mysqli

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Prepared statements** only. Because nowhere escaping is the same thing. In fact, escaping has absolutely nothing to do with whatever injections, and shouldn't be used for protection.

While prepared statements offer the 100% security when applicable.

Comment: How is it possible to inject with the latter? Given UTF-8 and that using `mysql_real_escape_string` of course implies using delimiters or int casts as well.

Comment: If you're looking for performance you should use real_escape_string instead of prepared statement because is twice faster. Details here: https://www.jimwestergren.com/pdo-versus-mysqli

Comment: @Pascut First, it says that PDO offers performance without penalty. Second and most important, **do not trade security for the performance**, you'll lose both. Nobody cares whether your hacked site is fast.

Comment: My comment is related to the question. Your answer haven't addressed the performance domain. But I agree with you, security first, performance later.

Answer (score 5):

Use `prepared statements` because after using this you  doesn't have to use  `mysqli_real_escape_string`. `prepared statements` doing this as by default.

Comment: Because `...do the same thing as mysqli_real_escape_string but it uses more lines...` OP wrote it in question. P.S. downvote not from me ;)

Comment: Well, I know I don't have to use mysqli_real_escape_string after using a prepared statement, but why shouldn't I just use mysqli_real_escape_string from the beginning and not use a prepared statement?

Comment: "`prepared statements` doing this as by default." Not true. Prepared statement (with no emulation) has other mechanizm.

Comment: "because you doesn't have to use mysqli_real_escape_string". yes. it rather makes you to use A LOT MORE functions to run single query. That's the point of the question: how to write less code, not more.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to forget (maybe not for you, but other developers you work with) to escape whereas it's very hard to use prepared statements incorrectly to cause a vulnerability. So prepared statements.