# SQLi - What is most safe?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What is the most safe approach?

This one:

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['id']);
echo $id;
```

Or this one:

```
$unsafe_id = $_GET['id'];
$safe_id = (int)$unsafe_id;
echo safe_id;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Casting to integer is in general safe, however you should consider using prepared statements. They are the best.

Comment: @biesior So I should rather use the `int` one, and not `mysqli_real_escape_string`?

Comment: For integers yes, however once again: you should use **prepared statements** then you don't need any of yours.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786295/should-i-use-mysqli-real-escape-string-or-should-i-use-prepared-statements

Comment: @Kama start here and follow the examples and read the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: You should research input Validation over Sanitation.

Comment: Here you go: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/update