# How do i use mysqli_real_escape

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been converting my site over from mysql to mysqli and am wondering how i use mysqli_real_escape_string like mysqli_real_escape_string. In other words, how do i treat the string with the new escape like the old escape would.

I uses to just do

```
mysql_real_escape_string($string);
```

But now i have to do

```
mysqli_real_escape_string(<-What should i put here?->,$string);
```

So what do i put in the first parameter to treat the string like the old escape?

Error:

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /var/www/frostbase/core/functions/general.php on line 22
```

Comment: You use it like you would the old mysql equivalent. What's your problem with applying it that way? Better yet, you should use prepared statements, now that you have the choice with mysqli.

Comment: Except that this version requires the first parameter to be a connection identifier and second parameter be the string you want to escape using procedural style code: http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: im getting this error, its in the comment

Comment: Have you read the documentation? It explains what it's expecting. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: you can use PDO database connector and prepared statements that doesn't need escape.

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Why_use_PDO.3F

Comment: ya i looked at it, but i'm not quite understanding it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [PHP Manual](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) the prototype is

```
string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )
```

That means as the first parameter you have to provide the mysqli link identifier, second parameter should be the string you want to escape

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$escapedValue = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, "yourString");
?>
```

Comment: I was looking at it too hard, now that you have pointed it out, i can't believe i missed it

Answer (score 2):

Its better to use prepared statements as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2353687/1965084) for security reasons. Mysql_real_escape_string might not be suffiecient to prevent sql injection e.g. because multibyte character sets can be abused despite the escape function ().[mysql_real_escape_string() versus Prepared Statements](http://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html).

Prepared statements in PHP can be used like this:

```
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
  $stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
  $stmt->bindParam(2, $value);
```

[More information on prepared statements in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 1):

All mysql* functions implicitly passed an opened connection around behind the scenes. In mysqli, you always have to pass the connection around explicitly. This is much better coding practice. For this, you have the choice between two styles, procedural and object oriented:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(...);

$string = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $string);
$string = $link->real_escape_string($string);
```

Even better yet, you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). See [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) for some background information.

Comment: Thanks bud, solved my problem. Forgot it was in a function and the link wasn't reaching it, will accept answer in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

Nobody told you that **you must not call this function manually**, in the application code.
One can use this function **only** as a formatting facility, to support manually parsed placeholders (if any). Otherwise there is a decent chance to allow an injection.

Most people do not understand the meaning of this function. They imagine it is intended to protect their queries from injection. While it is not.

Assuming such a protection is your primary goal, you have to learn that it's **prepared statement** that does this noble job.

Most people do not understand the meaning of prepared statements too, confusing the general idea of a prepared statement with very limited implementation offered by some APIs.

One offered by mysqli is practically unusable, for whatever case that differs from silly manual example. Thus, one have to invent their own database library, build upon API (for which APIs actually intended but for some reason used in raw form everywhere, which is wrong).

So, here goes a [safeMysql DBAL](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql#safemysql) which you can learn proper usage of this function from, or just start using instead of ugly raw API calls.