# PHP variable in SQL column name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to make a SQL update statement in php, and my column name need to be a variable.
I get these variables from jQuery ajax post method and i have them in PHP :

```
$variable = $_POST['variable']; 
$row = $_POST['row']; 
$field = $_POST['field'];
```

When i echo them out, i get the right values, for example:

```
echo $variable; 
echo $row;
echo $field;
```

And i get - martins, 2, firstname. In my database i have column with name - firstname. So, i try to  make this statement ( i know that i need to use prepared statement, but that is another question)

```
$sql = 'UPDATE ajax_example SET '.$field.'= "'.$variable.'" WHERE id = "'.$row.'"';
mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

If i change '.$field.' with name - firstname, then UPDATE is successful, so $variable and $row is defined correctly , but i need this column name as variable. I have seen about 15 posts, and i have tried each of hose codes but nothing. Is that realy impossible?

Comment: Escape your input variables, and please don't use `mysql_` functions anymore, use `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Comment: 1. Don't use `mysql_`. They're deprecated (and have been for a couple of years). Use `mysqli_` or `PDO`. Second of all, this code is insanely insecure.

Comment: Please, please, escape your input variables. Passing them directly into the statement will open doors for a classical attack, called "SQL injection".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape your variables, a basic example given your context...

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(/* config */);
$sql = 'UPDATE ajax_example SET ' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $field).'= "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $variable) . '" WHERE id = "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row) . '"';
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: Thank you! This works! :) But why escape is so necessary? And shoud i use PDO? PDO have some very big pluses?

Comment: @user3316619 Prepared statements are always better than pasting variables into your query. See [Is `mysql_real_escape_string` sufficient for cleaning user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353666/php-is-mysql-real-escape-string-sufficient-for-cleaning-user-input).

Comment: @h2ooooooo `mysql_real_escape_string` isn't sufficient, but `mysqli_real_escape_string` is fine - because it escapes against the connection that you provide it - whereas the `mysql_` variation does not - PDO **is** far better, but it's a huge deviation from what the OP has