# How to make the return of a $_POST in PHP permanent webpage content

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a form that I can post. I also have a sql database that it has a successful connection with. However, when I close the page out, the user input disappears. How can I make the user input part of the page content,almost like a guestbook kind of idea?

```
<p onclick="myFunction()">Click here to share your personal testimony</p>
<div id="formwindow">
    <form action="http://needjesuskneadjesus.org/perstest.php" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr; ?></span>
        <br>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr; ?></span>
        <br>
        Personal Testimony:<br> <textarea name="personalTestimony" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea><br>
        <input type="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("formwindow").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
</br>
<?php
    echo "Name: " . $_POST['name'];
?>
</br>
<?php
    echo "Email: " . $_POST['email'];
?>
</br>
<?php
    echo "Personal Testimony: " . $_POST['personalTestimony'];
?>
</br>
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. 
    // Check connection
    if($link === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    // Escape user inputs for security
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['email']);
    $personalTestimony = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, 
    $_REQUEST['personalTestimony']);
    // attempt insert query execution
    $sql = "INSERT INTO personalTestimony (name, email, testimony) VALUES 
    ('$name', '$email', '$personalTestimony')";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        echo "Thanks for sharing your personal testimony.";
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
    // close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
*/
?>
```

Comment: use cookies or session

Comment: you have to save the user input then put them again , one way to do this is by sessions. save them: `$_SESSION["name"] = $_POST['name']` then when building the page do : `echo "Name: ".$_SESSION['name'];`

Comment: Although not specifically asked about, take care to not echo unsanitary POST vars; use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) to store the users review, this will display the old one

```
<?php
session_start();

$name;
$email;
$personalTestimony;

if($link === false){
    die('ERROR: Could not connect.' . mysqli_connect_error());
}



if (!isset($_POST['name']) && !isset($_POST['email']) && !isset($_POST['personalTestimony'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name']);
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $personalTestimony = $_POST['personalTestimony']);


    // attempt insert query execution
    $sql = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO personalTestimony (name, email, testimony) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$personalTestimony'))";

    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        echo 'Thanks for sharing your personal testimony.';
    } else{
      echo 'ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. ' . mysqli_error($link);
    }

} elseif (!empty($_SESSION['name']) || !empty($_SESSION['email']) || !empty($_SESSION['testimony'])) {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['testimony'] = $personalTestimony;
    }

}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

I replaced 
    mysqli_real_escape_string to mysqli_prepare since it's less characters and provides more safety. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2353687/4205550).

This will only work until ether the session expires (You can configure this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8311400/4205550)) or the client clears their cookies.

Comment: `!isset() && !empty()` ?! . that condition will NEVER EVER happen !!! . also what do you mean by using `htmlentities` on the statement object that is returned from using `mysqli_prepare` which is used with wrong paramters!. Fred Gandt means by using `htmlentities()` using it to put the user input into your outputted html like `echo "your name is " . htmlentities($_POST['name'])` . man, you should test your code before posing it in as an answer. BTW I didn't down-vote your answer

Comment: @Accountantم Thanks for pointing that out, I've always done !isset() and !empty() out of habit, oops. I should have tested but didn't want to miss more of Halt and Catch Fire. I've rectified those issues now though.